# T-SQL Case statement strange behavior with newid() as randomness source

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

If I do the following to get a list of random-ish numbers in the range [1,3], it works just fine:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1 [value_of_rand]
FROM sys.objects
```

and I get nice things like this (all between 1 and 3).

```
3
2
2
2
1
....etc.
```

But if I then put the output of that same chained-random-value function into a CASE statement, it apparently does not produce only the values 1,2,3.

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CASE (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1)
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'one'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'two'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'three'
        ELSE
            'that is strange'
    END [value_of_case]
FROM sys.objects
```

It outputs:

```
three
that is strange
that is strange
one
two
...etc
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could it be that when presenting the number it's rounding it, but when evaluating it isn't? Try putting it in a variable and debugging/throwing the value out where you have "that is strange".

Comment: If I assign it to a variable and then do the case statement against that variable, it works fine, no strangeness. However, I think your method of debugging it is not possible. I get an error saying "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations." if I try to do something like this:

DECLARE @a int; select @a = (ABS(checksum(newid()))%3 + 1), CASE @a WHEN 1 THEN 'one' WHEN 2 THEN 'two' WHEN 3 THEN 'three' ELSE 'strange: ' + cast(@a as varchar(max)) END

Comment: you could always just remove the entire `WHEN 3` case and put the `three` in the `ELSE`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CASE (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1)
        WHEN 1
            THEN 'one'
        WHEN 2
            THEN 'two'
        WHEN 3
            THEN 'three'
        ELSE
            'that is strange'
    END [value_of_case]
FROM sys.objects
```

Actually executed:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CASE 
        WHEN (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1) = 1  THEN 'one'
        WHEN (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1) = 2  THEN 'two'
        WHEN (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1) = 3  THEN 'three'
        ELSE 'that is strange'
    END [value_of_case]
FROM sys.objects;
```

Basically your expression is non-deterministic and each time is evaluated so you can end up with `ELSE clause`. So there is no bug or catch, just you use it with variable expression and it is perfectly normal behavior.

This is the same class like [`COALESCE syntactic-sugar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

> The COALESCE expression is a syntactic shortcut for the CASE
>   expression. That is, the code COALESCE(expression1,...n) is rewritten
>   by the query optimizer as the following CASE expression:
>
> CASE
>
> WHEN (expression1 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression1
>
> WHEN (expression2 IS NOT NULL) THEN expression2
>
> ...
>
> ELSE expressionN
>
> END
>
> This means that the input values (expression1, expression2,
>   expressionN, etc.) will be evaluated multiple times. Also, in
>   compliance with the SQL standard, **a value expression that contains a
>   subquery is considered non-deterministic and the subquery is evaluated
>   twice. In either case, different results can be returned between the
>   first evaluation and subsequent evaluations**.

**EDIT:**

Solution:
**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/2801/0)**

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CASE t.col
        WHEN 1     THEN 'one'
        WHEN 2     THEN 'two'
        WHEN 3     THEN 'three'
        ELSE      'that is strange'
    END [value_of_case]
FROM sys.objects
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1 ) AS t(col)
```

Comment: Looking at the page for [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) it says, under **Simple CASE expression:** "Evaluates *input_expression*, and then in the order specified, evaluates *input_expression* = *when_expression* for each WHEN clause." It could be a documentation error, and your explanation seems to be right, but have you seen that the query is actually being rewritten that way once submitted? Just curious.

Comment: @srutzky There is on Connect error about  `COALESCE` which is unwrapped as CASE WHEN, this is the same case. `COALESCE` has warning in documentation, `CASE` not :( See https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/546437/

Comment: I looked at that Connect item and it is for `COALESCE`, not `CASE`. Also, it just says the same thing that the `COALESCE` documentation says (what you linked to in the answer). I am saying: is there any actual _proof_ that the expression is being rewritten as you suggest? I ask because the documentation for `CASE` implies that, in the Simple CASE scenario (which this is), the *input_expression* is only evaluated once. I realize that the behavior matches your explanation, but it would be nice to have something more definitive ;-).

Comment: Wow! Nice explanation. I added a link to this on the MSDN page for CASE...probably won't last long, but maybe it will save someone from the confusion I was having for a while.

Comment: @srutzky Yep, the doc does say that, but then ... the optimizer happens. And the SQL optimizer has a *lot* of leeway to move things around (more than any other language that I know of).  AFAIK, it is never clearly and definitively defined to us what what the optimizer's limits/boundaries are for this. And for scalar expressions, there's no way that I know of to find out for sure what it *is* doing because the Query Plan doesn't really go down into the detail of scalar expression's evaluation by parts.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem you are experiencing here is that `(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1)` isn't a value, it's an *expression* and SQL has the option of re-evaluating it whenever it wants to.  You can try various syntactical things like removing the extra parenthesis or a CTE.  That might make it go away (for now), but it might not, since logically it looks like the same request to the optimizer.

I think that the only sure-fire, supported way to stop this would be to save it first (to a temp table or a real one) and then use a second query to reference the saved values.

Comment: But how could that expression possibly produce a value that causes the ELSE branch of the CASE statement to be hit?

Comment: @Anssssss Because a `CASE` *expression* isn't like a C `switch` statement, the expression could be re-evaluated at each `CASE` conditional test and come up with different values..

Comment: I do not understand. Are you saying that (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1) can produce something other than 1,2, or 3?

Comment: @Anssssss No, I'm saying that on the `WHEN 1` branch it might evaluate to 3 and then on the `WHEN 2` branch it might evaluate to 1.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now. lad2025 has explained it better visually.

Answer (score 1):

I cant tell you why, it is indeed strange, but I can give you a workaround. Select the random values into a cte before trying to use them

```
;with rndsrc(value_of_rand) as
(
SELECT TOP 100 
    ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%3 + 1
FROM sys.objects
)
SELECT TOP 100 
CASE value_of_rand
    WHEN 1
        THEN 'one'
    WHEN 2
        THEN 'two'
    WHEN 3
        THEN 'three'
    ELSE
        'that is strange'
END [value_of_case]
from rndsrc
```

No more "that is strange"

Comment: This does work, but I am not sure how reliable it is.  The optimizer is allowed to move things around as it sees fit and could re-order it in the future, however, I suspect that as long as you keep the `TOP 100` with the expression in a CTE or subquery, it will probably stay stable.