# Why is this query returning null sometimes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why is the following code returning null sometimes.

```
SELECT 
    CASE ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 4
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Dr'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Master'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Mr'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Mrs'
    END
```

If I do the following instead:

```
DECLARE @n INT
SELECT @n = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 4

SELECT 
    CASE @n
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Dr'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Master'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Mr'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Mrs'
    END
```

It never returns null.

[image: Picture]

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's part of a bigger query where I can't easily set a variable

Comment: Are you _sure_ the first code returns null sometimes (and that you've pasted it exactly as is)? Because I don't think that's possible...

Comment: Have you considered `ELSE 'Mrs'` instead of the final `WHEN`?

Comment: @ZLK agreed...I don't see how a case could never be hit in the first query.

Comment: @ZLK It's part of a bigger query and this it what I tested separately in a new query. Hitting Execute a few times and getting null sometimes

Comment: Then my guess is that the problem lies somewhere in the bigger query.  Maybe you should post that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added image

Comment: @ZLK added image

Comment: Interesting.. I am also getting NULL for most of the times...

Comment: me too getting nulls over go 10

Comment: @maSTAShuFu never knew about go 10. Thanks

Comment: GO 10 to execute the batch 10 x

Comment: You have answer here [T-SQL Case statement strange behavior with newid() as randomness source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484626/t-sql-case-statement-strange-behavior-with-newid-as-randomness-source)

Comment: Interesting. So it produces a new NEWID() at each stage of the case statement, meaning there's a (3/4)^4 chance it falls through (and becomes null because of the lack of ELSE)

Comment: @ShakeerMirza Thanks

Comment: Nice analysis   @ZLK

Comment: Yes, that's known issue. That's not only for NEWID(), for RAND() as well

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression - You can find the explanation here. This issue is due to how Case gets executed when you use an expression instead of a simple INT